# How to show response size on Swagger

Tags: .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Is there a way to display or show the response size on Swagger 3.0 .Net core?

Like Postman

[image: postman response size]

If that possible, could you help me with this please?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by **size**?

Comment: If by "size" you mean the response `Content-Length`, then it's already displayed in response data, provided that the tested API server actually returns the `Content-Length` header in responses. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvCgT.png